# Consecutive $n$-gonal numbers whose sum is an $(n+1)$-gonal number.

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that the sum of two consecutive $n$-gonal numbers is an $(n+1)$-gonal number, given $n\geq3$.

Well, this might be untrue since this my own observation.

Comment: Your comment to a proposed answer suggests that the conjecture should read more like: "For $n\geq 3$, **there exist** two consecutive $n$-gonal numbers whose sum is an $(n+1)$-gonal number."

Also, a definition of "$n$-gonal" number is probably in order. Wikipedia's ["Polygonal Number" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_number) gives this formula for the $k$-th $n$-gonal number:
$$P(n,k) = \frac{k(k-1)}{2}(n-2) + k$$ Is this what you intend?

Comment: No, just read the question and comment carefully once.

Comment: The conjecture, as written (and carefully read), has the form of a "universal" claim: **Any pair** of consecutive $n$-gonal numbers is an $(n+1)$-gonal number. However, your comment  to Jorge's counterexample ---"it might be true for some big $n$"--- suggests that you don't expect the statement to hold for **any pair** of these numbers, but at least **some pair**. The "there exists" phrasing captures that distinction in meaning.

Comment: In any case, since this is "[your] own observation", you should provide some of the examples you've observed that led you to the conjecture.

Comment: You know what I was actually trying to ask.Prove that the sum of two consecutive triangular numbers is a perfect square. S the.  I could have proven but I did not try to. Immediately 1+4=5 came to my mind and I added this to the question. A minute later I knew I had blundered.

Comment: By the way I wanted to prove the formulae in Wikipedia article polygonal numbers. Can I do so with my background of half semester single variable calculus. I will try on my own . Just tell the required background.

Comment: Using the formula, "Two consec triangulars make a square" falls out immediately (and *always*), since $$P(3,u)+P(3,u+1)=\frac12u(u+1)+\frac12(u+1)(u+2)=(u+1)^2=P(4,u+1)$$ For "Two consec squares make a pentagonal" requires $u$ & $v$ where $$P(4,u)+P(4,u+1)=P(5,v) \quad\to\quad 2 + 4 u + 4 u^2 = 3 v^2 - v$$ Your example $1+4=5$ corresponds to $u=1$, $v=2$. Are there more? Maybe. Solving for $u$ gives $$u = \frac16 (1 \pm \sqrt{48u^2+48u+25})$$ which tells us $48u^2+48u+25$ must be a perfect square. "When is this a square?" isn't always an easy question. Search "Pell's Equation" for background.

Answer (score 1):

This is false.

$9+16=25$, the two numbers on the left are square numbers and the one on the right is not a pentagonal number.

---

For triangular numbers it is true since $\frac{(n-1)n}{2}+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{2n(n)}{2}=n^2$

Comment: It might be true for some big n.